# How to implement a second function in php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_text', 5 );

 function show_text() {
echo "Buy this from our store. This is the best (echo $title) in the industry. By using this (echo $title) you save more.";

$tittle = woocommerce_template_single_title();
echo $tittle; 
}
```

This is what I try to implement in WooCommerce below my products. The text is displayed, but I can't get the second function output ($title).

Anyone has any idea please?

Thanks

Comment: What does `var_dump($tittle);` return?

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding template for **`woocommerce_template_single_title`** is located in the WooCommerce folder **`templates/single-product/title.php`** and the active code is just this line:

```
the_title( '<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' );
```

So you can use [**`the_title()`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) WordPress function directly as it's already echoed and you don't really need a second function… But if you want to set it in a variable you have to use instead [**`get_the_title()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/).

So your code will be something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_text', 5 );
function show_text() {

    $title = get_the_title();
    echo "<p>Buy this from our store. This is the best $title in the industry. By using this $title you save more.</p>";

    // Optional - Displaying title directly (without echo)
    the_title( '<h1 itemprop="name" class="product_title entry-title">', '</h1>' );
}
```

The Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works.

Answer (score 0):

Assignment of `$title` variable should be done before using it.Don't use echo in echo statements.That should be like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_text', 5 );    
   function show_text() {    
    $tittle = woocommerce_template_single_title();
    echo "Buy this from our store. This is the best $title in the industry. By using this $title you save more.";
    echo $tittle; 
}
```

========================================================================

If `woocommerce_template_single_title()` not work. Then use `get_the_title()` function.eg.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'show_text', 5 );
 function show_text() {
   $tittle = get_the_title();
   echo "Buy this from our store. This is the best $title in the industry. By using this $title you save more.";
echo $tittle; 
}
```